# Ionic Framework v2 Getting Started Example Not Working

Tags: ubuntu, ionic-framework, ionic2

**Environment**

```
AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance: Linux 4.4.0-75-generic #96-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 20 09:56:33 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

node v7.10.0

npm v4.2.0

cordova v7.0.0

ionic v2.2.3
```

I had the same error with node v6.10.0 and npm v3.10.10.

**Commands I Executed**

`ionic start abc blank`

`cd abc`

`ionic serve`

**Error**

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-75-generic

npm ERR! argv "/home/ubuntu/apps/node-v7.10.0-linux-x64/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "ionic:serve" "--" "--v2" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port" "35729"

npm ERR! node v7.10.0

npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 137

npm ERR! ionic-app-base@0.0.0 ionic:serve: `ionic-app-scripts serve "--v2" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port" "35729"`

npm ERR! Exit status 137

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Failed at the ionic-app-base@0.0.0 ionic:serve script 'ionic-app-scripts serve "--v2" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port" "35729"'.

npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.

npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ionic-app-base package,

npm ERR! not with npm itself.

npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:

npm ERR!     ionic-app-scripts serve "--v2" "--address" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "8100" "--livereload-port" "35729"

npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:

npm ERR!     npm bugs ionic-app-base

npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:

npm ERR!     npm owner ls ionic-app-base

npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:

npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2017-05-05T21_47_32_471Z-debug.log

There was an error serving your Ionic application: There was an error with the spawned command: serve
```

**Update**

I tried getting the latest version of ionic-app-scripts. I get the following warnings when I run:

`npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev`

**Error**

```
ubuntu@foobar:~/dev/abc$ npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev
npm WARN deprecated object-keys@0.2.0: Please update to the latest object-keys
ionic-app-base@0.0.0 /home/ubuntu/dev/abc
└── @ionic/app-scripts@1.3.7 

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):

npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
```

*Any help would be greatly appreciated.*

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up my question suraj, the formatting looks much better now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the issue.

I was running my Ubuntu instance on an EC2 t2.micro instance. The t2.micro only has 1 CPU and 1 GB of ram.

I upgrade my EC2 instance to a t2.medium and was finally able to build and run the Ionic Framework v2 sample code.